# Cypress tests passing in GUI failing in CI

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm testing the change in visibility of an element when the page scrolls. In the cypress GUI this test passes everytime.

[image]

Yet it fails everytime when run on the command line / in CI:

```
  home page desktop
    ✓ desktop: top section info (1923ms)
    1) desktop: use cases info


  1 passing (18s)
  1 failing

  1) home page desktop
       desktop: use cases info:
     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 15000ms: expected '<span.css-ifijsl>' to be 'visible'

This element `<span.css-ifijsl>` is not visible because its parent `<div.css-1nm341b>` has CSS property: `opacity: 0`
```

This is the assertion with the helper function:

```
function scrollIntoView(dataTestId: string) {
  // fix for the issue with cypress scroll
  return cy
    .get(`[data-testid=${dataTestId}]`)
    .should('exist')
    .then(el => {
      el[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'nearest' })
      return el
    })
}

function checkUseCasesVisibility() {
  cy.findByTestId('homepage-use-case-1').should('not.be.visible')
  scrollIntoView('abcde')
  cy.findByTestId('homepage-use-case-1').should('be.visible')
```

cypress config

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://controld-webapp:9000",
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/e2e/build/cypress/e2e",
  "viewportHeight": 900,
  "viewportWidth": 1440,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 15000,
  "requestTimeout": 15000,
  "video": false,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "scrollBehavior": "center"
}
```

Comment: could you provide the html code of that section?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it or find the issue?